# How to launch the new GNOME 42 screenshot tool from the Activities Overview after upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

It appears that when I upgraded my Ubuntu to 22.04 it carried the old screenshot utility with it, but I also have the new GNOME 42 screenshot way when I push my <kbd>Print screen</kbd> key on my keyboard.

So when I type "screenshot" in the activity overlay, I get the old Ubuntu 21.10 way.

[image: old screenshot tool]

When I hit my <kbd>Print screen</kbd> key, I get the new Ubuntu screenshot UI.

[image: new screenshot tool]

Is there a way to unite the two, so that typing "screenshot" in my activity overlay brings up the new GNOME 42 screenshot UI?

I upgraded my installation using the `do-release-upgrade` utility, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

To only use the new screenshot tool, just uninstall the old one (`gnome-screenshot`) by running:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-screenshot
```

You will be able to then search for "screenshot" in the Overview and select *Take a Screenshot* (see screenshot below) to take a screenshot (duh ) using the new screenshot tool.

[image: "screenshot" search in Overview]